# Need output of OLAP query

Tags: mysql, olap, olap-cube

```
 select itemID, storeID, custID, sum(price) 
 from Sales F 
 group by storeID, itemID, custID with cube(storeID, custID);
```

So what should be the output of this query? I mean which attributes could be null?
Will I have:

```
I, S,    C
I, S,    null
I, null, null
```

or

```
I, S,    C
I, S,    null
I, null, null
I, null, C
```

Comment: What was the output when you ran this query? That should tell you where the `NULL` values can be

Comment: Actually I don't have the database and the data set up.

Comment: -1 Voted to close as Too Localized - you've answered your own question, which was specific to your own schema (which isn't described), and answered it without any explanation. No other person could conceivably benefit from this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is going to be:

```
I, S,    C
I, S,    null
I, null, null
I, null, C
```